# What formula to list (bl 1, bl 3, bl 7 ) for matched date?

Tags: google-sheets

Formula would return bills (Rent, Utilities, etc.) for matched date (5/1/20)

What formula do I use to list items matching a date and separating each one with a comma? *list not in different cell but kept in the same, results just separated with comma *Google Sheets Thank you!

In others "words":
[Display all matching values in one comma separated cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561213/display-all-matching-values-in-one-comma-separated-cell)
BUT answer didn't work.

Basically the opposite of:
[Comma separated list into matched columns pairings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593084/comma-separated-list-into-matched-columns-pairings/57698827#57698827?newreg=641a10783ac84c2786bf1092d787442e)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Bills are in column B and dates are in column A both on tab Sheet1.  And you are on tab 2 in cell B2. And 5/1/20 is in cell A2.

```
=JOIN(", ",FILTER(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=A2)
```

Comment: You're AWESOME. Thank you SO much!! God bless (1 Corinthians 15 KJV).

Comment: Thank you so much again. To help anyone who needs this, =IF(I5="","",IFERROR(JOIN(", ",FILTER($D$4:$D$28,$A$4:$A$28=I5)),"")) solves the errors for matching blanks and no matches. e.g. 1/1/20 will return a blank if no bill is due.

Answer (score 0):

Maybee you can make a sample sheet and share this. With youre input data and a cell with you're desire output? i don't really understand what you want and why the awnser from another Q didn't work.